# Find totals by week

Tags: excel, excel-formula, week-number

I have a spreadsheet with various dates(a) (sequential) and pay(G).
I would like to fill in the Week total column(h) with the total made for the week in the last week of the row. In the attached picture, I manually entered the values to show what I want to do.

[image: Example]

Added table as requested

| Date | Start | End | Subject | TimeSpent | Pay | WeekTotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/10/2024 |  |  |  |  | 533.42 |  |
| 01/12/2024 |  |  |  |  | 595.44 | 1128.86 |
| 01/15/2024 |  |  |  |  | 496.20 |  |
| 01/16/2024 |  |  |  |  | 248.10 |  |
| 01/16/2024 |  |  |  |  | 248.10 | 992.40 |
| 01/23/2024 |  |  |  |  | 471.39 | 471.39 |
| 01/29/2024 |  |  |  |  | 595.44 |  |
| 01/30/2024 |  |  |  |  | 285.32 |  |
| 01/31/2024 |  |  |  |  | 372.15 |  |
| 02/01/2024 |  |  |  |  | 372.15 | 1625.06 |
| 02/06/2024 |  |  |  |  | 372.15 | 372.15 |
| 02/12/2024 |  |  |  |  | 124.05 |  |
| 02/13/2024 |  |  |  |  | 372.15 |  |
| 02/14/2024 |  |  |  |  | 434.18 | 930.38 |

Can someone help with the formula?

Scott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the older versions without Office 365, This will work in All versions:

```
=IF(WEEKNUM(A2)=WEEKNUM(A3),"",SUMPRODUCT($F$2:$F$15*(WEEKNUM(--$A$2:$A$15)=WEEKNUM(A2))))
```

[image]

OR

This is shorter, but it requires that the dates are sorted:

```
=IF(WEEKNUM(A2)=WEEKNUM(A3),"",SUM($F$2:F2)-SUM($G$1:G1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott. Worked well for my needs.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way of doing this:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _WeekN,WEEKNUM(+A2:A20),
     _WTotal, MMULT(N(_WeekN=TOROW(_WeekN)),G2:G20),
     IF(LOOKUP(_WeekN,_WeekN,ROW(A2:A20))=ROW(A2:A20),_WTotal,""))
```

---

This is the workaround for the total of `100` rows:

```
=LET(
     _Data, FILTER(A2:G100,A2:A100<>""),
     _WeekN,WEEKNUM(TAKE(_Data,,1)),
     _WTotal, MMULT(N(_WeekN=TOROW(_WeekN)),TAKE(_Data,,-1)),
     IF(LOOKUP(_WeekN,_WeekN,SEQUENCE(ROWS(_WeekN)))=SEQUENCE(ROWS(_WeekN)),_WTotal,""))
```

---

Comment: Mayukh, That worked perfectly but one issue. My spreadsheet goes to 100 rows. Rows 21-100 are filled in when needed. If I modify your formuls to go to row 100, the totals don't show up. Is there a way to compensate for the blank rows until they are filled in.

Comment: @ready4data it is bit heavy resource because the use of `MMULT()` with `TOROW()`, You need to extend the range, I couldn't make it simple, but you should opt for the one posted by Scott Craner Sir

Comment: @ready4data you can change your source into a `Structured Reference` aka `Tables` so the formula will auto resize

Comment: Thanks, I'll use Scot Craners solution. That worked all the way down the rows.

Comment: @ready4data no issues at all. Just like I said it is simple and easy to use.